# When I try to automatic weight bone with mesh then mesh goes to another place

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-weights

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvC3rHNGxx53vCX1w_DBl6VJiUTbNsEU/view?usp=sharing]

After joining bone with mesh, this is happening. I also provided a link to my file here - [image]

Comment: Try applying _scale_ and/or _rotation_  (Ctrl+A > Rotation & Scale) to the mesh before applying the automatic weights.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.